# In Youtube API, I get empty pages after the second page

Tags: java, youtube-api

I try to get all the live videos of youtube api at a given time.

However, after the two firsts pages that contains 50 results each, all the others pages are empty.

```
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/7Mn5oZUWkgMIU4kfKx7cq0D0nDI\"","items":[{THIS ONE IS OK WITH 50 RESULTS}],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CDIQAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1994},"regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/wp4SIiAGHN1uLiJgvLGoMdQoehs\"","items":[{THIS ONE IS OK TOO WITH 50 RESULTS}],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CGQQAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1994},"prevPageToken":"CDIQAQ","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/3zCHC7x--dhww0e7udfLQn3DB5Y\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CJYBEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1988},"prevPageToken":"CGQQAQ","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/pGfYwQfcIDdD05OBzqTVFbdg39E\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CMgBEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1986},"prevPageToken":"CJYBEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/qtrckZRTf7czKQNL5nQpXRu7X5A\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CPoBEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1985},"prevPageToken":"CMgBEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/gTY6oWopjQcy6Cuf1MGQqYGYfog\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CKwCEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1993},"prevPageToken":"CPoBEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/umiznrtjy7vmWkIJ5Hsm8wtU0W0\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CN4CEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1985},"prevPageToken":"CKwCEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/thJws1H1pJJPtOkVeq6L6VGabn8\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CJADEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1988},"prevPageToken":"CN4CEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/TaDYlGeeLP2H1xanLHVTtmt_DNg\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CMIDEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1995},"prevPageToken":"CJADEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/w3wj8nt1NHhxyh-fuWLJ1v5ncvU\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CPQDEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1989},"prevPageToken":"CMIDEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/r1hbVDG2ANenKRichmZxj0J2dws\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CKYEEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1996},"prevPageToken":"CPQDEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/hdDkPLk2aNKrJLZ8tnMnCGqhUy8\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CNgEEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1994},"prevPageToken":"CKYEEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/OjWuZOr5rNl_HasCmAEhF5cAN9E\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CIoFEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1995},"prevPageToken":"CNgEEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/g8lxb3uVDwSfamhbbxFlyoVKBTg\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CLwFEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1986},"prevPageToken":"CIoFEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/wnTWwe1b-0gy--2ochuizsAjD9o\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CO4FEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1993},"prevPageToken":"CLwFEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/N1y4dp3ngAItfwukyLLitFQFDPA\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CKAGEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1981},"prevPageToken":"CO4FEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/F8oNrDOjlKMvHjzPIF7cJqfK_zo\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CNIGEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1986},"prevPageToken":"CKAGEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/JCWNr1NCzgl0GLh66R-SHeokbW8\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CIQHEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1992},"prevPageToken":"CNIGEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/uTbvXolYwtv5Zt4mpLQVHCQsbF4\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CLYHEAA","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1999},"prevPageToken":"CIQHEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
{"etag":"\"7991kDR-QPaa9r0pePmDjBEa2h8/xxkZZRO_iCVgmWLAsBW4Qk6VdcU\"","items":[],"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","pageInfo":{"resultsPerPage":50,"totalResults":1995},"prevPageToken":"CLYHEAE","regionCode":"FR"}
```

Here is the code used :

```
List<SearchResult> searchItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    YouTube.Search.List searchListRequest = youTubeService.search().list("snippet");
    searchListRequest.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);
    searchListRequest.setEventType("live");
    searchListRequest.setType("video");
    searchListRequest.setVideoCategoryId(GAMING_VIDEO_CATEGORY);
    searchListRequest.setOrder("viewCount");
    searchListRequest.setSafeSearch("none");
    searchListRequest.setPrettyPrint(true);
    String nextToken = "";
    do {
        if (!nextToken.isEmpty()) {
            searchListRequest.setPageToken(nextToken);
        }
        SearchListResponse searchListResponse = searchListRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(searchListResponse);
        if (searchListResponse.getItems().size() > 0) {
            searchItemList.addAll(searchListResponse.getItems());
        }
        nextToken = searchListResponse.getNextPageToken();
    } while (nextToken != null);
```

I don't get why the third to last request "items" field is empty. Are there some kind of restrictions from Youtube API?